# how to create a path alias?

Tags: unix, alias

So "cs" will be mapped to "/College/" so that I can run the command "cd cs"?

Comment: Check out `z`; it's a dynamic `cd` to the directories you use most: https://github.com/rupa/z

Answer (score 12):

I believe you are asking about how to create a symbolic link (or symlink) like:

```
ln -s College cs
```

Although, there are other ways to speed up your workflow, such as setting the CDPATH:

```
export CDPATH=.:~/:/College/
```

Or you could even make "cs" an alias that will perform the action "cd /College/":

```
alias cs='cd /College/'
```

If you did the above, you would type `cs` instead of `cd cs` to get there.

**See also**

- [ln](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ln.html) - man page for the ln command from the POSIX 2004 standard
- [symlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html) - man page for the C function to create symlinks from the POSIX 2004 standard

Comment: Thanks! the "ln -s College cs"