# How to execute a program in a symbolic link without the ./?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have created a symbolic link to my Matlab installation path in my home directory, so that I can type `matlab` and run it from anywhere, instead of typing out the entire path.

`ln -s /exp/comm/matlab-R2014b/bin/matlab matlab`
Adding permissions to execute this:
`chmod +x matlab`

However, I am always required to type `./matlab` instead of `matlab` for this to execute. Is there any way to get rid of `./` and just type the name of the symbolic link and have it run correctly?

Comment: Add the directory to your PATH. Or define an alias. Whichever suits your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variety of options:

1. add the directory with the symlink to your `PATH`.  See [Adding a directory to PATH in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360889/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-ubuntu)  Also, try not put the `.` in your PATH.  https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default explains why this is bad.
2. use an `alias` as described by [how to create a path alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869671/how-to-create-a-path-alias)
3. create a shell function such as seen in [Unix Bash Alias Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598648/unix-bash-alias-command)
4. implement your own shell